# How can i write in a file JSON Format result?

Tags: java, json

I'm new to this point , I have file contains 50.000 tweets with JSON format , i need to convert or make it readable . I tried to use this code but How can i make it write in a file ?

```
package analysis;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class p {
public static void performAnalysis() {
    File tweets;

    String[] categories;
    tweets = new File("/home/user/Desktop/tweets.txt");
    categories = tweets.list();

    for (int i = 0; i < categories.length; ++i) {
        String category = categories[i];
        File file = new File(tweets, category);
        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                String rawTweet = sc.nextLine().trim();
                if (rawTweet.equals(""))
                    continue;
                Tweet parsedTweet = new Gson().fromJson(rawTweet, Tweet.class);
               //System.out.println(parsedTweet.getBody());

            }
            sc.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

the other class is

```
package analysis;
import java.io.Serializable;
public class Tweet implements Serializable{
private long ID;
private String body;

public Tweet(long tweetID, String body)
{
    this.body = body;
    ID = tweetID;
}

public Tweet(long tweetId)
{
    ID = tweetId;
}
public String getBody()
{
    return body;
}

public void setBody(String body){
    this.body = body;
}
public long getID()
{
    return ID;
}

public void setId(long tweetId)
{
    ID = tweetId;
}
}
```

the file which contains 
tweets like

```
    {"filter_level":"low","retweeted":false,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"possib
ly_sensitive":false,"truncated":false,"lang":"en","in_reply_to_status_id_str":   null,"id":712044789663924224,"extended_entities":{"media":[{"sizes":{"thumb":{"w":150,"resize":"crop","h":150},"small": {"w":340,"resize":"fit","h":227},"medium":{"w":600,"resize":"fit","h":400},"large":{"w":1024,"resize":"fit","h":683}},"source_user_id":38142624,"media_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/media/Cdv_qOUW4AAfExX.jpg"","type":"photo",,"id":710442467104055296,"media_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Cdv_qOUW4AAfExX.jpg","expanded_url":"http://twitter.com/standardsport/status/710442468760748032/photo/1","source_user_id_str":"38142624","indices":[120,140],"source_status_id_str":"710442468760748032","source_status_id":710442468760748032,"id_str":"710442467104055296"},{"sizes":{"small":{"w":340,"resize":"fit","h":227},"thumb":{"w":150,"resize":"crop","h":150},"medium":{"w":600,"resize":"fit","h":400},"large":{"w":1024,"resize":"fit","h":683}},"source_user_id":38142624,"media_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/media/Cdv_qOpW4AEpErk.jpg","id":710442467192135681,"media_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Cdv_qOpW4AEpErk.jpg","expanded_url":"http://twitter.com/standardsport/status/710442468760748032/photo/1","source_user_id_str":"38142624","indices":[120,140],"source_status_id_str":"710442468760748032","source_status_id":710442468760748032,"id_str":"710442467192135681"}]},"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"timestamp_ms":"1458599681665","in_reply_to_status_id":null,"created_at":"Mon Mar 21 22:34:41 +0000
```

second part

```
2016","favorite_count":0,"place":null,"coordinates":null,"text":"RT @WHUFC_News: West Ham are the only team in the top half of the Premier League without a player in the England squad. ,"contributors":null,"retweeted_status":{"filter_level":"low","retweeted":false,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"possibly_sensitive":false,"truncated":false,"lang":"en","in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"id":712035466573422594,"extended_entities":{"media":[{"sizes":{"thumb":{"w":150,"resize":"crop","h":150},"small":{"w":340,"resize":"fit","h":227},"medium":{"w":600,"resize":"fit","h":400},"large":{"w":1024,"resize":"fit","h":683}},"source_user_id":38142624,"media_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/media/Cdv_qOUW4AAfExX.jpg""id":710442467104055296,"media_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Cdv_qOUW4AAfExX.jpg","expanded_url":"http://twitter.com/standardsport/status/710442468760748032/photo/1","source_user_id_str":"38142624","indices":[104,127],"source_status_id_str":"710442468760748032","source_status_id":710442468760748032,"id_str":"710442467104055296"},{"sizes":{"small":{"w":340,"resize":"fit","h":227},"thumb":{"w":150,"resize":"crop","h":150},"medium":{"w":600,"resize":"fit","h":400},"large":{"w":1024,"resize":"fit","h":683}},"source_user_id":38142624,"media_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/media/Cdv_qOpW4AEpErk.jpg","display_url":"pic.twitter.com/OFpmAARFZR","type":"photo","id":710442467192135681,"media_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Cdv_qOpW4AEpErk.jpg","expanded_url":"http://twitter.com/standardsport/status/710442468760748032/photo/1","source_user_id_str":"38142624","indices":[104,127],"source_status_id_str":"710442468760748032","source_status_id":710442468760748032,"id_str":"710442467192135681"}]},"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"created_at":"Mon Mar 21 21:57:38 +0000 2016","favorite_count":51,"place":null,"coordinates":null,"text":"West Ham are the only team in the top half of the Premier League without a player in the England squad.,"contributors":null,"geo":null,"entities":{"symbols":[],"urls":[],"hashtags":[],"media":[{"sizes":{"thumb":{"w":150,"resize":"crop","h":150},"small":{"w":340,"resize":"fit","h":227},"medium":{"w":600,"resize":"fit","h":400},"large":{"w":1024,"resize":"fit","h":683}},"source_user_id":38142624,"media_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/media/Cdv_qOUW4AAfExX.jpg","type":"photo","id":710442467104055296,,,"source_user_id_str":"38142624","indices":[104,127],"source_status_id_str":"710442468760748032","source_status_id":710442468760748032,"id_str":"710442467104055296"}],"user_mentions":[]},"is_quote_status":false,"source":"<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for
```

Third part

```
iPhone<\/a>","favorited":false,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"retweet_count":47,"
id_str":"712035466573422594","user":{"location":"East London","default_profile":false,"statuses_count":87630,"profile_background_tile":false,"lang":"en","profile_link_color":"CC3366","profile_banner_url":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/346499404/1457051522","id":346499404,"following":null,"favourites_count":2879,"protected":false,"profile_text_color":"333333","verified":false,"description":"Largest independent West Ham account. News, Transfer Rumours, Images, Stats, Match Updates and more. Est. August '11.","contributors_enabled":false,"profile_sidebar_border_color":"DBE9ED","name":"West Ham News","profile_background_color":"DBE9ED","created_at":"Mon Aug 01 11:00:44 +0000 2011","default_profile_image":false,"followers_count":44318,"profile_image_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/705551398650388481/_o-dfUjR_normal.jpg","geo_enabled":false,"profile_background_image_url":"http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme17/bg.gif","profile_background_image_url_https":"https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme17/bg.gif","follow_request_sent":null,"url":"http://www.westham-news.com","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"notifications":null,"profile_use_background_image":true,"friends_count":508,"profile_sidebar_fill_color":"E6F6F9","screen_name":"WHUFC_News","id_str":"346499404","profile_image_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/705551398650388481/_o-dfUjR_normal.jpg","listed_count":240,"is_translator":false}},"geo":null,"entities":{"symbols":[],"urls":[],"hashtags":[],"media":[{"sizes":{"thumb":{"w":150,"resize":"crop","h":150},"small":{"w":340,"resize":"fit","h":227},"medium":{"w":600,"resize":"fit","h":400},"large":{"w":1024,"resize":"fit","h":683}},"source_user_id":38142624,"media_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/media/Cdv_qOUW4AAfExX.jpg","id":710442467104055296,"media_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Cdv_qOUW4AAfExX.jpg","expanded_url":"http://twitter.com/standardsport/status/710442468760748032/photo/1","source_user_id_str":"38142624","indices":[120,140],"source_status_id_str":"710442468760748032","source_status_id":710442468760748032,"id_str":"710442467104055296"}],"user_mentions":[{"id":346499404,"name":"West Ham News","indices":[3,14],"screen_name":"WHUFC_News","id_str":"346499404"}]},"is_quote_status":false,"source":"<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone<\/a>","favorited":false,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"retweet_count":0,"id_str":"712044789663924224","user":{"location":null,"default_profile":true,"statuses_count":16826,"profile_background_tile":false,"lang":"en","profile_link_color":"0084B4","profile_banner_url":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/559823246/1355067792","id":559823246,"following":null,"favourites_count":84,"protected":false,"profile_text_color":"333333","verified":false,"description":null,"contributors_enabled":false,"profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","name":"John mcginty","profile_background_color":"C0DEED","created_at":"Sat Apr 21 19:44:37 +0000 2012","default_profile_image":false,"followers_count":123,"profile_image_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/690829546032074752/8qjDgLXe_normal.jpg","geo_enabled":true,"profile_background_image_url":"http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png","follow_request_sent":null,"url":null,"utc_offset":0,"time_zone":"London","notifications":null,"profile_use_background_image":true,"friends_count":216,"profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","screen_name":"jmmc88","id_str":"559823246","profile_image_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/690829546032074752/8qjDgLXe_normal.jpg","listed_count":8,"is_translator":false}}
```

Comment: you have to explain what you want in order for people to answer you. from your code, i can see your input has already seen json format. so it's very confusing that what else you want to do.

Comment: Instead of printing results using system.out . I want to receive results in a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this question is really about formatting an querying a JSON file, I'd skip the programming part and just use any JSON browsing tool out there. E.g. try opening that file in [Firefox Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/).

Another option is to use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), and redirect the output to a file (assuming you use some UNIX/UNIX-like shell):

```
cat tweets.json | jq . > output.json
```

That would be a large file, though. You can use ja's querying syntax to make a few smaller files.

Comment: Yes . You are right . I want to make it readable . Thanks for the link . I'll try it

Comment: But file of tweets is text file not json . How can I parse or write it with your command

Comment: What's the format, then? Can you post some lines here?

Comment: i put sample of the tweets json formats which exists in text file , can you please check it ?

Comment: I edited the command to be cat tweets.txt | jq . > output.json

Comment: It's a JSON file. JSON is a text-based format (unlike binary-based ones, such as JPEG) so it's also a text file (that is, you can open it in a text editor and see meaningful content). Try to change the file suffix from ".txt" to ".json" and open in FireFox.

Comment: Sorry . You mean that I should try your command and results will be opened in Firefox ? i tried your command and it created json file with empty results . Notice that the file I have for tweets with txt format so how can I write tweets.json . It's not exists . Right ?

Comment: No. Change the file suffix and drag it to a firefox window. Chrome might also work.

Comment: yes you are right , sorry for not getting you well . can you please check this too i tried this command  grep -Po '"text":.*?[^\]",' tweets.json >> output.txt and gave me texts. Does  this text of the tweet only or any text in the file?

Comment: I'm afraid that's not going to work. Grep is line-based, JSON is not. So even if that works for one file, it may not work for the next. Grep has no concept of  a "text of a tweet", just lines that do or do not match a regular expression

Comment: I got what you mean but iam asking about if I want to get text of tweet only

Comment: Dude, use jq. You need a program that understands JSON. Can you post the file online somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for your help and time . I voted for your help really. Unfortunately the file is large size , i can share samples like i posted , but what i got that each tweet is stored in Json format started with " { filter " until another " { filter " appeared . Am i right ?

Comment: You could say that, but it's a bit of a hack. The thing is, you can't just cut a JSON file, you need to cut it at the right place, or else you end up with an invalid file. Can you post the first 2 MB of it somewhere? E.g. some GitHub repo/Dropbox?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply . Ok I'll try